# Displaying static files in Django runserver

Tags: python, html, django, web

I am having a problem where when I try to run my website through the runserver command, it doesnt display any of the images.

(I am very new to django, and website building at all)

this is the html in the template:

< img src="../../../static/Website_header.png" width="800" height="200" alt=""/> (without the whitespace)

and this is the settings.py:

http://pastebin.com/KvdrF1L2

---

Edit: When I tried to click display image in new tab this was shown: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9JzR.jpg

Answer (score 2):

You should not have direct links to your static files.

On top of your template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

Your image tag:

```
<img src="{% static 'images/test.png' %}" />
```

"images/test.png" is addressed relative to your static folder:

static
------ images
------------ test.png

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files

Comment: Hey thanks alot for answering! I tried this, but still, it didnt display the image.


This is not in the template:   
< img src="{% static 'images/Website_header.png' %}" />

and this is the settings.py (still the same) : http://pastebin.com/g2v5F7qP

I still get the 404 not found error


Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/static/Website_header.png

Comment: Your address in the original post was "/static/Website_header.png" so you probably don't have an images folder like in my example. If that's the case use: < img src="{% static 'Website_header.png' %}" />